# Equation for cloud-like curve

Tags: geometry, plane-curves

It might be a bit naive question, but I'm looking for an equation to describe a curve that looks like a typical cloud clipart icon. This is an example (not sure how to make it smaller): [image: cloud icon]

I think it could be something like [epicycloid](https://www.2dcurves.com/roulette/roulettee.html#epicycloid) (particularly, ranunculoid), but I'm not sure how to make it more oblong.

Comment: Transform the coordinates to $x,y$ coords, and then dilate the $x$ coordinate. The downside of this process will be that the cloud will look a bit too perfect.

Comment: You could try something like $r = 2+0.2\cos2\theta+|0.8\cos3.5\theta|$.

Answer (score 0):

To get those images, you could freely choose finitely many connection points forming a convex set and connect these connection points with smooth curves with positive (or negative) curvature.